# How to run .php script multiple times in batch using cmd?

Tags: php, batch-file, cmd

I have a small php script that looks like this :

```
<?php
$argument1 = $argv[1];
echo "passed Value:".$argument1;
 //do something with passed value 
 //echo processed value
?>
```

I want to run it multiple times using cmd.

This is how I run it currently :

```
c:\php\php.exe MyScript.php 1
```

I want to run the above cmd line multiple times for different values ranging from 1 to 100.

Could anyone tell me how I can run it multiple times for different values passed to it?

---

#### Note:

I want to be able read the output of each php call and copy it

Comment: You could make a script implement a loop iterating over that number interval and calling your php script in each iteration. A _possible_ language to implement such script would be php, actually, or any shell language installed...

Comment: "read the output of each php call and copy it" ? Read it on screen? Or into a variable? Copy to file?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Read it from cmd window and copy and paste it manually to text file or save the php output to a text file automatically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(FOR /L %x in (1,1,100) DO c:\php\php.exe MyScript.php %x)>output.txt 2>&1
```

`>output.txt` redirects STDOUT to a file. `2>&1` redirects STDERR to the same place.

(Note: this is a command line syntax. To use it in a batchfile, use `%%x` instead of `%x`)

Comment: I pasted this on cmd :(FOR /L %x (1,1,4) DO c:\php\php.exe MyScript.php %x)>output.txt 2>&1 and I get 1 was unexpected this time ! I wanted to test if it writes output to text file! does it create the text file or should i create it ?

Comment: `>` creates the file (and deletes it, if it already exists). I don't have php installed, so I can't test. What do you get, if you just use `c:\php\php.exe MyScript.php 1`?

Comment: If i run that line i get the value of php echo which is : passed Value:1 . i want those php echo results in text file instead of seeing them only on cmd window. so if i run it for small range 1-4 i should get passed Value:1,passed Value:2,passed Value:3,passed Value:4 on a text file as well

Comment: Shouldn't this be for /l %x **IN** (1,1,100)?

Comment: correct, @DennisvanGils. (Copy-Paste-Error...). Corrected.

Comment: @user1788736 I'm guessing that's the reason for the `1 was unexpected` error, it expected **in** first.

Comment: Does this method of calling php script waits for first php to finish before the next php call is made ?

Comment: don't konw php. Can't you try? If it does not, use `... DO start /wait c:\php\php.exe ...`

Comment: i tried it for php code that involves php curl and the only runs for first passed value and then it stops(without using do start / wait)! Then i used FOR /L %x IN (65,65,99) DO start /wait c:\php\php.exe myCurlScript.php %x and i get no php output on text file!

Comment: try `FOR /L %x in (1,1,100) DO (start /wait c:\php\php.exe MyScript.php %x >>output.txt 2>&1)`

Comment: I tried it . it opens another cmd prompt window very fast and closes it and output.txt file is created but no data on it !

Answer (score 2):

For doing it in the shell itself:

```
FOR /L %parameter IN (start,step,end) DO command
```

For example:

```
FOR /L %x IN (1,1,100) DO c:\php\php.exe MyScript.php %x
```

---

For doing it in a .bat file:

```
FOR /L %%parameter IN (start,step,end) DO command
```

For example:

```
FOR /L %%x IN (1,1,100) DO c:\php\php.exe MyScript.php %%x
```

However, I don't know if this will output the outcome.

Source: [SS64](http://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html)

Edit: changed %%x to %x and replaced 1 by %x -- thanks both of you :D

Comment: I suggest: **FOR /L %%x IN (1,1,100) DO c:\php\php.exe Myscript %%x**

Comment: Thanks for replies. anned20 i tried this for smaller ranger  by typing the line you posted on cmd promot(FOR /L %%x (1,1,4) DO c:\php\php.exe MyScript.php 1) and i get this error :%%X was unexpected at this time.

Comment: Uhm, I'm not really confident with batch. So what does that do @hherger?

Comment: `%%x` syntax is for use in batchfiles. If you use it on command line, use `%x` only.

Comment: In principle it does what you suggested. The difference is, that (by the second %%x) Myscript gets the index as a parameter. And this parameter is taken as input by the script thru the statement _$argument1 = $argv[1];_

Comment: @Stephan Thanks that fixed the problem . Is there a way to write output of each php call to text file ? now i see the output on cmd window?

Comment: @user1788736 Check the answer of Stephan

Comment: You also should edit your answer to have your second example use **IN** in the for command. This wouldn't work.

Comment: Thank you @DennisvanGils Landgenoot xD

Comment: @anned20 geen probleem, was verder een goed antwoord. Ik zou er echter wel nog een note inzetten over %% voor batch, % voor cmd